# Подстановка переменной пути в rsync

Tags: bash

Почему подставляется вместо `NEW_FILE_PATH /home/jaime/bash/~/gb/174_3/`, а не `~/gb/174_3/`

В терминале ввожу:

```
NEW_FILE_PATH="~/gb/174_3/"
SOURCE_FILE_PATH="~/connect3/filt*"
numGbox=174
password="111"
rsync -avzP --rsh="sshpass -p $password ssh -l ts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ts@gbox-${numGbox}:${SOURCE_FILE_PATH} ${NEW_FILE_PATH}
receiving incremental file list
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/home/jaime/bash/~/gb/174_3/": Not a directory (20)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(652) [Receiver=3.1.1]

jaime@Lannisport:~/bash$ echo $NEW_FILE_PATH

~/gb/174_3/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что символ `~` — это такой же **относительный** элемент пути, как, и например, `a` или `123`, когда употреблён **внутри** строки.

вот **относительно** текущего каталога запущенного вами процесса (а текущий каталог — это одно из *свойств* процесса) и вычисляется **абсолютный** путь.

---

попробуйте явно указать **абсолютный** путь. например, заменив строку

```
NEW_FILE_PATH="~/gb/174_3/"
```

на

```
NEW_FILE_PATH=$HOME/gb/174_3/
```

хотя, вполне возможно, достаточно будет «вытащить» путь из строки, куда вы её помещаете:

```
NEW_FILE_PATH=~/gb/174_3/
```

---

**иллюстрация**:

```
$ p1="~/123"
$ p2=~/123
$ p3=123
$ echo $p1 $p2 $p3
~/123 /home/al/123 123
$ realpath $p1 $p2 $p3
~/123: No such file or directory
/home/al/123: No such file or directory
123: No such file or directory
$ mkdir -p $p1 $p2 $p3
$ realpath $p1 $p2 $p3
/home/al/~/123
/home/al/123
/home/al/123
```

Comment: спасибо. С этим стало понятно.

Изначально проблема в том, что я задаю NEW_FILE_PATH через read:

`read -a NEW_FILE_PATH -p "Введите путь, куда хотите скопировать: "`

Comment: @nlv, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: спасибо. С этим стало понятно.

Изначально проблема в том, что я задаю NEW_FILE_PATH через read:

`read -a NEW_FILE_PATH -p "Введите путь, куда хотите скопировать: "`

~/gb/174_3/

И получается, что там он всегда в ковычках. Можно как-то сделать так, чтобы через read работало.

Comment: @nlv, то, что вы сейчас спрашиваете, «тянет» на новый вопрос, так как к текущему относится очень слабо. не стесняйтесь задавать новые вопросы — здесь это приветствуется.