# Указание в rsync абсолютного пути с использованием ~

Tags: bash, rsync

связанный вопрос: [Подстановка переменной пути в rsync](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449214/178576)

---

Задаю `NEW_FILE_PATH` через `read`:

```
read -a NEW_FILE_PATH
```

Ввожу `~/gb/174_3/`

```
rsync -avzP --rsh="sshpass -p $password ssh -l ts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" stalin@box:/home/jaime/test.txt ${NEW_FILE_PATH}

receiving incremental file list
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/home/jaime/bash/~/gb/174_3/": Not a directory (20)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(652) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

Я ожидаю, что копирование произойдёт в `~/gb/174_3/`, а происходит в `/home/jaime/bash/~/gb/174_3/`.

Как дать понять rsync, что указан абсолютный путь, т.е. чтобы копирование происходило в `~/gb/174_3/`?

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что код не специфичен для bash, т.е. на любом shell'е пойдёт? Вроде никакого необычного синтаксиса нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не могу точно сказать, т.к. я имею опыт общения только с bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут возникает некоторое количество «подводных камней».

во-первых, процесс, запрашивающий ввод от пользователя икс, может выполняться от имени пользователя игрек. соответственно, *домашние каталоги* «с точки зрения» скрипта и с точки зрения пользователя икс — будут совершенно разными.

во-вторых, встаёт вопрос безопасности.

ведь решение «в лоб«

```
eval NEW_FILE_PATH=$NEW_FILE_PATH
```

может привести к весьма «интересным» последствиям. например, если пользователь введёт что-нибудь вроде `;rm -rf *`.

более безопасным будет что-нибудь вроде:

```
NEW_FILE_PATH="${NEW_FILE_PATH/#\~/$HOME}"
```

Comment: Shell ломает мне мозги каждый раз, когда я его пытаюсь понять )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, есть (с моей точки зрения) гораздо более «мозгодробительные» языки. например, те же [apl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), [j](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), [k](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) и им подобн.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо. Решил с помощью eval.